# Modulus Division

Tags: java, modulus

I recently enrolled in a Java class and I have a question regarding modulus division.

I get an example in my textbook:

```
( 100 - 25 * 3 % 4 ) = 97
```

How does this equal 97? I’ve tried every single possiblity and I just can’t seem to figure it out.

Can someone please be so kind to break it down for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: % is for modulus ... 25*3 = 75 , 75%4 = 3 and 100-3 =97 .(* has higher precedence)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Operator Precedence

`( 100 - ((25 * 3) % 4) ) = 97`

`25*3=75`

`75 MODULO 4=3`

`100-3=97`

That's it.

#### When you're unsure about operators' priority put parentheses  everywhere.

Comment: So that would be (100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)) = 97 with parentheses?

Comment: Yes, look at this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html * and % have the same precedence, they are evaluated from left to right, first the * then the % and finally the -.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your answer! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The operators *, /, and % are called the multiplicative operators. They have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

So whenever there is A op1 B op2 C and both op1 and op2 are *, / or % it's equivalent to

(A op1 B) op2 C

```
  25 * 3 % 4 -> a * b % c 
  (25*3)%4->(a*b)%c
```

(-) operator is right to left.so  - operator performs the calculation after right side expression completed.
   so the answer is
    100-(25*3)%4=100-3=97